# Spotfire: DateTimeNow() -1 Month to limit line graph

Tags: datetime, ironpython, spotfire, linegraph

I am working in Spotfire 7.0.1

I have a line graph displaying Actual vs. Plan dates for a project currently in progress. The plan line (grey) extends to the end of the project timeline. The Actual line DID extend to the as well, but I used a Custom Expression to limit it to the current Month. However, I want to push it back 1 month. ie if we are in November the Actual line graph should stop at October.

Current expression:  `If([Actual] <= DateTimeNow(), 1, null) as [Actual]`

This expression limits my [Actual] line to November (today's date is 11/03/16), however I want to push it back 1 Month to **October**.

[image]

Any Suggestions?

Comment: What's the value of [Actual]? Look into DateDiff

Answer (score 2):

You are going to want something like

```
If([Actual] <= DateAdd("month",-1,DateTimeNow()),TRUE,FALSE)
```